# BibLatex -> group multiple citations by the same author

Tags: biblatex, formatting, luatex, citing, biber

As some of you know, my university is **very** strict regarding their citations guidelines. So I come to thee again for some custom formatting hacks.

For those who can read Dutch, you can find the guidelines in the screenshot below.
[image: Guidelines]
For those who aren't that fluent in Dutch, I translated the guidelins in the MWE example below. This image is an output of that MWE [image: translated guidedelines]

Basically,

- the ; should be replaced by , when citing multiple authors (I guess this should be easy?)
- when citing the same author with multiple publications, the author should not be repeated (I guess this is nearly impossible?)

I deliberately mixed the chronological order of the citations because biblatex lets me do that...

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[bibstyle=ext-authoryear,
innamebeforetitle=true,
citestyle=authoryear,
maxnames=3,
maxbibnames=99,
sortcites,
sorting=ynt,
uniquename=init,
giveninits=true,
doi=false,
isbn=false,
dashed=false,
backend=biber]{biblatex}

%\usepackage{filecontents} This package is obsolete?

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@book{Taeldeman1979,
    langid = {dutch},
    location = {{Hilversum}},
    title = {Some book},
    date = {1979-01-01},
    publisher = {publisher},
    author = {Taeldeman, Johan}
}

@book{Taeldeman1988,
    langid = {dutch},
    location = {{Hilversum}},
    title = {Some other book},
    date = {1988-01-01},
    publisher = {publisher},
    author = {Taeldeman, Johan}
}

@book{RysTaeldeman2007,
    langid = {dutch},
    location = {{Hilversum}},
    title = {A book by Rys and Taeldeman},
    date = {2007-01-01},
    publisher = {publisher},
    author = {Rys, Bryan and Taeldeman, Johan}
}

@book{Villena-Ponsoda2009,
    langid = {dutch},
    location = {{Hilversum}},
    title = {A book by Villena-Ponsoda},
    date = {2009-01-01},
    publisher = {publisher},
    author = {Villena-Ponsoda, Rachel}
}

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

When quoting multiple sources by different authors, mention all authors with corresponding dates, between round brackets.
Order the citations chronologically (oldest publication first), \textbf{and devide them by a ,}

\begin{itemize}
    \item cf. \parencites{Taeldeman1988,Villena-Ponsoda2009,RysTaeldeman2007}
    \item renders: (Taeldeman 1988; Rys en Taeldeman 2007; Villena-Ponsoda 2009)
    \item should be:  (Taeldeman 1988\textbf{,} Rys en Taeldeman 2007\textbf{,} Villena-Ponsoda 2009)
\end{itemize}

Publications by the same author, however, need to be grouped, even if they break the chronology
\begin{itemize}
    \item cf. \parencites{Taeldeman1988,Villena-Ponsoda2009,Taeldeman1979}
    \item renders: (Taeldeman 1979; Taeldeman 1988; Villena-Ponsoda 2009)
    \item should be: (Taeldeman \textbf{1979, 1988,} Villena-Ponsoda 2009)
\end{itemize}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Thanks to whoever can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The separator between two citations is controlled by `\multicitedelim`, its default value is a semicolon followed by a space, but it can easily be persuaded to print a comma followed by a space

```
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

The `authoryear` and `authortitle` style families have `-comp` styles that only print the same author/editor name once in citations. In your case it is easiest to simply switch from `bibstyle=ext-authoryear, citestyle=authoryear,` to

```
style=ext-authoryear-comp,
```

but you could also go for `bibstyle=ext-authoryear, citestyle=authoryear-comp,`. Since you are using `biblatex-ext` anyway, `style=ext-authoryear-comp,` seems much simpler.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear-comp,
  sorting=ynt,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  maxnames=3,
  maxbibnames=99,
  uniquename=init,
  giveninits=true,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false,
  dashed=false,
  backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{filecontents*}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{Taeldeman1979,
  langid    = {dutch},
  location  = {Hilversum},
  title     = {Some book},
  date      = {1979-01-01},
  publisher = {publisher},
  author    = {Taeldeman, Johan}
}
@book{Taeldeman1988,
  langid    = {dutch},
  location  = {Hilversum},
  title     = {Some other book},
  date      = {1988-01-01},
  publisher = {publisher},
  author    = {Taeldeman, Johan}
}
@book{RysTaeldeman2007,
  langid    = {dutch},
  location  = {Hilversum},
  title     = {A book by Rys and Taeldeman},
  date      = {2007-01-01},
  publisher = {publisher},
  author    = {Rys, Bryan and Taeldeman, Johan}
}
@book{Villena-Ponsoda2009,
  langid    = {dutch},
  location  = {Hilversum},
  title     = {A book by Villena-Ponsoda},
  date      = {2009-01-01},
  publisher = {publisher},
  author    = {Villena-Ponsoda, Rachel}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

When quoting multiple sources by different authors, mention all authors with corresponding dates, between round brackets.
Order the citations chronologically (oldest publication first), \textbf{and devide them by a ,}

\begin{itemize}
    \item cf.\ \parencites{Taeldeman1988,Villena-Ponsoda2009,RysTaeldeman2007}
    \item renders: (Taeldeman 1988; Rys en Taeldeman 2007; Villena-Ponsoda 2009)
    \item should be:  (Taeldeman 1988\textbf{,} Rys en Taeldeman 2007\textbf{,} Villena-Ponsoda 2009)
\end{itemize}

Publications by the same author, however, need to be grouped, even if they break the chronology
\begin{itemize}
    \item cf.\ \parencites{Taeldeman1988,Villena-Ponsoda2009,Taeldeman1979}
    \item renders: (Taeldeman 1979; Taeldeman 1988; Villena-Ponsoda 2009)
    \item should be: (Taeldeman \textbf{1979, 1988,} Villena-Ponsoda 2009)
\end{itemize}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image: (Taeldeman 1988, Rys en Taeldeman 2007, Villena-Ponsoda 2009)//cf. (Taeldeman 1979, 1988, Villena-Ponsoda 2009)]

Comment: wow, I could not believe how (relatively) easy this one was. Thank you @moewe for your quick response and answer!